# Create a document that references a collection's ObjectId

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Have a postSchema that reference an ObjectId from a User Schema:

```
var postSchema = new Schema({
    text: { type: String, required: true, maxlength: 140 },
    _creator: { type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'User', required: true },

});
```

In my postController, how do I set the _creator attribute when creating a new Post?:

```
exports.postCreatePost = function(req, res, next) {
console.log(req.body);

var newPost = new Post({
    text: req.body.text,
    _creator: req.body.User._id // What is this supposed to be in order to reference User's ObjectId?
});

newPost.save(function(err, newPost) {
    res.status(200).json(newPost);
});
}
```

Receiving "Unexpected string in JSON at position 30" error when attempting to Post this JSON using Postman with that ObjectId for an existing user:

```
{
    "text": "first test post"
    "_creator": "5a13b3c695fcb47ea5c71308"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here your postSchema should be like this,

```
var postSchema = new Schema({
    text: { type: String, required: true, maxlength: 140 },
    _creator: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User', required: true },
});
```

`_creator` property should have type as `mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId`

Comment: Changed property to this and am still receiving the same error.

Comment: Can you please share your req.body?

Comment: it is this which is what I am sending through Postman:

`{
    "text": "first test post"
    "_creator": "5a13b3c695fcb47ea5c71308"
}`

Comment: Ohk but when you do console.log(req.body) what is it printing?

Comment: it is not reaching that log statement. My terminal is printing
`Running on port 3000...
POST /newpost 400 22.880 ms - 1164
SyntaxError: Unexpected string in JSON at position 30` ...

However if I change my schema to just have the text property, I am able to create a post. So I know it is not my routing that is at error at least.

Comment: I think that is because you are not putting comma( , ) after first value in your json. Before creator there should be a comma.